# For loop not continuing after first iteration

Tags: php

So I've written the for loop as shown below, and for some reason, after the first time through the loop, the loop stops. In this case, I am trying to send the value 4 through, and it fails the if statement that checks for a string "true" from the checkRes function. That is all that function does is return strings. It is my understanding of loops that it will keep going through the loop until the statement at the top is met, or it is exited.
 What am I doing wrong below?

```
 // assume $avaliable = 4;
 for ($i=$avaliable;10>$i;$i++) {
    $check = checkRes($i, $people_no, $booking_date);
        if ($check === "true") {
            switch($i) {
                case 0: $newResTime = "6 PM"; break;
                case 1: $newResTime = "6:30 PM"; break;
                case 2: $newResTime = "7 PM"; break;
                case 3: $newResTime = "7:30 PM"; break;
                case 4: $newResTime = "8 PM"; break;
                case 5: $newResTime = "8:30 PM"; break;
                case 6: $newResTime = "9 PM"; break;
                case 7: $newResTime = "9:30 PM"; break;
                case 8: $newResTime = "10 PM"; break;
                case 9: $newResTime = "10:30 PM"; break;
                case 10: $newResTime = "11 PM"; break;
            }
            // Replace next line with your return from the chatbot
            echo "We're sorry, that time isn't avaliable, but a reservation at $newResTime has been made!";
            exit;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Remove your `exit;`

Comment: `$check` is true so it's entering into the `if` and on it you have an `exit;` so it makes the loop to stop

Comment: this code is crazy. Why does your check res function only return a bool? why not return the time directly? What the hell does an iteration index have to do with someone's reservation?

Comment: exit; will stop the flow of loop. remove it

Comment: @aldrin27 Removing the exit is irrelevant for two reasons: 1. $check isn't evaluating to true, so it never drops into that if. 2. Even if it was hitting that exit, I would see the echo text, and I'm not

Comment: @GyandeepSharma see above comment

Comment: @Rafael It doesn't only return a bool, it has the possibility of returning four different strings, true happens to be one of them and the one I'm testing for in this code block. Also, this is about 15 lines of a greater 400 line codebase, so there is a lot more going on that isn't shown here

Comment: @AdamMcGurk ah I gotcha, just bad design.

Comment: @Rafael how so?

Comment: Hey Adam, just going through some of your other questions and I noticed this one that I might be able to shed some light on, given if it's still open/unsolved. Regarding `if ($check === "true")`. That is checking for a string instead of a possible boolean. If you're looking for boolean, remove the quotes around "true" to read as `if ($check === true)`.

Comment: Oops, I just saw [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46721720/for-loop-not-continuing-after-first-iteration#comment80411410_46721720) above, scratch that ^ however, you could use an `||` operator to check for a string or boolean.

Comment: I edited my above, have you tried `if ($check === "true" || $check == true)`? Or have you solved it? Is there anything coming back from error reporting? http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php - This `$avaliable` seems to be mispelled, could it be `$available` by any chance?

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yeah, I did end up figuring it out, I need to post an answer soon, I added an else on the if statement, and it worked! The exact code is at my other job, so I can't do it right now, but I do need to post it haha

Comment: @AdamMcGurk ah cool, that's good news Adam. Glad to hear it was solved. *Cheers*

Answer (score 2):

You are currently using [`exit`](http://php.net/exit) as a "default" solution. But it always terminates execution of the program (since that is what [`exit`](http://php.net/exit) does).

Instead do this

```
switch($i) {
    case 0: $newResTime = "6 PM"; break;
    case 1: $newResTime = "6:30 PM"; break;
    case 2: $newResTime = "7 PM"; break;
    case 3: $newResTime = "7:30 PM"; break;
    case 4: $newResTime = "8 PM"; break;
    case 5: $newResTime = "8:30 PM"; break;
    case 6: $newResTime = "9 PM"; break;
    case 7: $newResTime = "9:30 PM"; break;
    case 8: $newResTime = "10 PM"; break;
    case 9: $newResTime = "10:30 PM"; break;
    case 10: $newResTime = "11 PM"; break;
    default: echo "..."; break;
```

Comment: This didn't work because the program never makes it to the switch statement, because $check doesn't evaluate to true, so it never makes it to that exit in the if statement. Even if it did make it to that if statement, I'm not seeing the echo